# explain proxy.config.json features angular 5

Tags: angular

```
"/api/*": {
  "target": "https://localhost:8000/api",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/api": ""
  },
  "changeOrigin": true
}
```

Please provide detailed use of each feature in this code snippet

thank you for help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
   "/api/*": {
      "target": "https://localhost:8000",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      },
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
```

1. `target:"api/*"`:
    All requests made to `/api/` from within your application will be forwarded to
   `target": "https://localhost:8000/api`
2. `"secure": false,`:
    A backend server running on HTTPS with an
   invalid certificate will not be accepted by default. If you want to,
   you need to set `secure: false`.
3. `"logLevel": "debug"`
      To help debug whether or not your proxy
   is working properly, you can also add the logLevel option as
   follows: Possible options for logLevel include `debug`, `info`,
   `warn`, `error`, and `silent` (default is info).
4. `"pathRewrite": { "^/api": ""   },`
   pathRewrite setting says that if the path matches `^/api` (i.e. if it starts with /api) then rewrite that portion with the empty string (i.e. remove it from the path), so all the request to `https://localhost:8000/api`  will go to `https://localhost:8000`
5. `"changeOrigin": true`: If you need to access a backend that is not on localhost or when you’re using some virtual proxies (such as configured with Apache2) on your backend set it to true.

proxy [`options`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#options) provided in this package is from underlying [`node-http-proxy`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy)

Proxying Support might help you to get rid off some **[`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)** exceptions during the development stage but There isn't much the client application can do about these exceptions The server must be configured to accept the application's requests.
***[`I want to add CORS support to my server`](https://enable-cors.org/server.html)***

**NOTE**: The `proxy` configuration is intended to proxy calls when running the dev server via `ng serve`. After you run `ng build` you are responsible for the web server and its configurations.

Answer (score 0):

From the **[`docs`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)**

> Using the proxying support in webpack's dev server we can highjack
>   certain URLs and send them to a backend server. We do this by passing
>   a file to --proxy-config
>
> Say we have a server running on http://localhost:3000/api and we want
>   all calls to http://localhost:4200/api to go to that server.

Also you can read why we need to do this from here https://itnext.io/angular-cli-proxy-configuration-4311acec9d6f