# When path in proxy.conf.json changed the Java app does not recognize change

Tags: angular, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I have an Angular 4 app, and I want it to point to a different URL for the backend (which is a java/spring app). When I had this problem on my localhost (it not being able to connect to my locally stood up backend) - I fixed it by adding this proxy.conf.json code (specifically the /api and /auth):

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://[::1]:8080",
    "secure": false
  },
  "/auth/*": {
    "target": "http://[::1]:8080",
    "secure": false
  },
  "*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

I now want to test this by pulling against my backend stoodup as a pod in a Rancher environment. I try to have it point to the right backend code via the below changes:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://fake-app1.my-fake-url.com",
    "secure": false
  },
  "/auth/*": {
    "target": "https://fake-app1.my-fake-url.com",
    "secure": false
  },
  "*": {
    "target": "https://fake-app1.my-fake-url.com",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

But when I look at the browser console it still shows up as going to localhost:8080 for API calls. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: Did you restart after making the change?

Comment: I did an npm start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in webpack.dev.js: `SERVER_API_URL:` ""`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I changed for JHipster version `5.1.0`:

webpack/webpack.dev.js

```
...
   devServer:
     proxy:[{
       target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081'
     }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting changeOrigin to true? Looks like it might be needed if the backend is on a different host than the front end?

> "changeOrigin": true: If you need to access a backend that is not on localhost or when you’re using some virtual proxies (such as configured with Apache2) on your backend set it to true.

See

- https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#options
- [explain proxy.config.json features angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125574/explain-proxy-config-json-features-angular-5)