# Proxy enable in angular 11

Tags: angular, proxy, config

I am trying to access external post api https://ing.east.com/store_new with token keys from angular.

I have enabled proxy by using proxy-conf.js and have changed package.json.

I am getting **403 forbidden error which I get same in postman and browser.**

How could I know the proxy is enabled and working. If I use **npm  start** I don’t get error and information regarding proxy started.

Please help me I’m breaking my head since one week.

Proxy.conf.js{
‘/api’:’https://ing.east.com/store_new ’,
Secure: false,
Changeorigin: true

ngstart serve —-proxyconfing ‘src/proxy-conf.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125574/explain-proxy-config-json-features-angular-5/51126942#51126942

Comment: 403 error Check your BE

Comment: @Vikas whether proxy config includes headers and parameters while redirecting or headers and parameters need to be added in proxy-config.js file. If yes how to do it. Please help me

Comment: Google cloud api returns The token supplied is invalid as reponse even if correct keys are passed. How this need to be rectified